# SQL Server 2008 trigger doesn't work, why?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I have a table called `tblReservations` with follwing columns:

```
reserv_ID (int), aptID (int), client_ID (int), 
start_date (datetime), end_date (datetime), 
details (nvarchar(max)), confirmation (bit)
```

What trigger should is to compare two dates `start_date` for new reservation and `end_date` for existing reservation in `tblReservation` for specific `aptID`.

If `start_date < end_date` trigger must prevent insertion of new reservation for that `aptID`.

I wrote this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewReservation
    on tblReservations
    after insert
    as
    begin
        declare @aptID int
        declare @start_date datetime
        declare @end_date datetime

        select @aptID=aptID, @start_date=start_date from inserted
        select @end_date=end_date from tblReservations
        where aptID=@aptID

        if @end_date>@start_date
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
    end
```

Why does this trigger not work?

please help

Comment: Can't you just use a check constraint `CHECK (start_date <= end_date)`?

Comment: any trigger wirtten where you set values from inserted or deleted to a scalar variables is wrong. It will not correctly handle multi-row inserts, updates or deletes. You can never assume these won't happen.

Comment: Aside from the multirow issue, you are likely not  considering that there are many rows in the tblReservations for a particular apt id.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the multiorw issue that others have brought up, you are likely not considering that there are many rows in the tblReservations for a particular apt id.

Plus you do not want to insert the record and then get rid of it, you want the record to not go in. therefore an instead of trigger is a better bet.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewReservation
    ON tblReservations
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

        INSERT tblReservations (<put field list here>)
        SELECT <put field list here>
        FROM inserted i
        JOIN (SELECT aptid, MAX(reservationid)AS reservationid FROM tblReservations GROUP BY aptid)  maxid 
            ON i.aptid = r.aptid
        JOIN    tblReservations r 
            ON r.reservationid = maxid.reservationid
        WHERE r.enddate<i.startdate


    END
```

Comment: ok, but now i get this error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NewReservation, Line 15
The multi-part identifier "r.aptid" could not be bound.

Comment: That's becasue I changed the alias while I was writing it and missed a refernce. r.aptid  should be maxid.aptid

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is you are assuming inserted is a single row.

Try:

```
Select top 1 @aptID=bb.aptID, @start_date=start_date
from inserted as aa
join
(
  select Max(start_date) as Start_Date from inserted 
) as bb
on aa.Start_Date =bb.Start_Date
```

But you should think about changing your logic so that the record never gets inserted in the first place if the date is wrong.

Comment: +1 exactly - a trigger might be called once for multiple `INSERT` and thus `Inserted` would contain multiple rows...

Comment: This still won't work correctly for multi row inserts. If you ever are assigning to scalar variables from `inserted` inside a trigger it is probably broken.